# Why is the cors-anywhere Proxy Giving 404 Error?

Tags: javascript, java, proxy, cors, microservices

I have a Java microservice hosted on http://localhost:7777/microservices/json_db_data. I'm building the front-end of my application in JavaScript, and I tested the GET request using this code:

```
const request = new XMLHTTPRequest();
const url = 'http://localhost:7777/microservices/json_db_data';

request.open("GET", url);
request.send();

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(request.response);
}
```

However, running this code gave me this error:
**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**
After doing some research, I found that I needed to use a proxy to add the header. I used the same code from above, but changed the 'url' variable to prefix the proxy:
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://localhost:7777/microservices/json_db_data.
However, running the code again with this new proxied URL gave me this error: 
 **GET https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://localhost:7777/microservices/json_db_data 404 (Not Found)**. 
And this further info: **Not found because of proxy error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7777**. 
I found this very odd because I tested the proxy with other URLS, and it worked for google.com, jsonplaceholder.typicode.com, and other websites. Has anyone else experienced this problem and/or knows the fix for this? Thanks.

Comment: localhost is only "accessible" to the **local host**

Comment: @Bravo I made my own proxy with Node.js and it worked, guess that was the problem then